# breakdown monthly report to weekly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005, crystal-reports-2010

I was trying to generate a monthly report but I have no idea how to break it down in weeks. e.g when i generate January my output report should be divided in 4 week - First week/Second week/Third week/Fourth week OF JANUARY - is this even possible? Should it be done before saving to database or SQL will do? I have a datetime field called RecordDate

I am using SQL Server 2005,VS 2010 and CR for VS2010.

Comment: To answer your questions:"First week/Second week/Third week/Fourth week OF JANUARY - is this even possible?" Yes, it is possible. "Should it be done before saving to database or SQL will do?" - The question makes no sense. If you would like more feedback, it might help if you post some sample data and if you're feeling really energetic, a sample of the output structure... You will find that people will try to put about as much effort and thought in to their responses as you do in to your question.

Comment: Sorry for that, as indicated in my question I have a source datetime field named `RecordDate` this is where i will collect data for my report, my concern is how will i classify those specific date.

Comment: e.g 8-1-2014 should be classified as Week 1 and 8-30-2014 will be under week 4 and so on and so forth.

Comment: Requirement is definetly possible but solution is lengthy and that can't be totally answerd... if you have tried to some extent will try to help from there.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing too, my problem is how will I classify each date to what week . I guess in this situation it's a matter of personal restriction and classification. So far what I have right now is just a summary of each month with no breakdown.

Answer (score 0):

Given your `datetime` field `RecordDate`, the following SQL will give the week of the month (starting at 1)

```
select (((datepart(d, RecordDate)-1) / 7)+1)
```

if you group by that, you should be able to produce a breakdown by the weeks in a month.

Of course, doing it this way some of the 'weeks' will not be 7 days long. It may be that you really want to group by the week of the year, ie.

```
select datepart(wk, RecordDate)
```

In each case you will need to produce labels. If you're going to do this in SQL then in the first case to get a label like 'week 1 of month 7' it'll be something like

```
select 'week ' + cast( (((datepart(d, RecordDate)-1) / 7)+1) as char(1)) 
+ ' of month ' + cast(datepart(month, RecordDate) as varchar(2)) 
from Table 
group by (((datepart(d, RecordDate)-1) / 7)+1), datepart(month, RecordDate)
```

You'd have to go round the houses a bit to get a label like 'week 1 starting in month 7' for the second case (I will leave this as an exercise for the reader)